# checking if two item in two different list have similar values using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have struggled for hours to come up with the best algorithm to check if 2 values in list1 matches 2 values in list2. For example:

```
list1 = [1,1,3,4]
list2 = [1,1,5,7]
```

Basically I want it to match the positions and also match duplicates.

What I have done:

```
b =  [item * 1 == item in list1 for item in list2]:
```

I am not getting the desired result. I would like to achieve this using a list comprehension.

Comment: `not getting the desired result`—What _is_ the desired result?

Comment: isn't `item * 1 = item` always...? I see after that `in list1 for item in list2` what does that mean? How come you have `:` at the end of the row?

Comment: the colon at the end of the row was left there in error sorry

Comment: the desired result expected is to get matching numbers identified from the two list variable. i thought that was well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the zip of the lists (which creates pairs of matched elements), using list comprehension to make a list of 1's if a pair matches, and 0 if it doesn't, and sum the list to see how many positional matches there are:

```
>>> list1 = [1,1,3,4]
>>> list2 = [1,1,5,7]
>>> num_matches = sum([1 if item1==item2 else 0 for (item1, item2) in zip(list1, list2)])
2
```

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Comment: Great! Thanks for selecting my answer as correct, please up-vote as well if you feel so moved!